# Using Laravel's artisan without composer in Windows

Tags: windows, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm using [laraPack](http://fian.my.id/larapack/) because I can't use composer at all (for reasons)
so how can  I use `php artisan` abilities without composer?
Is there any other way to use it without composer? What is it?
Maybe another way to make `artisan` file executable instead of composer?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you don't need composer, just PHP.
What happens when you run `php artisan`? What error(s) do you get, if any?
Just make sure to run `php artisan` within the root of your laravel project folder.